# Vagrant VM connect to remote host

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a Vagrant VirtualBox VM running Debian Linux. I want to connect from inside the VM to another host on my private network (say, `192.168.25.111`).

My network inside the VM looks like this:

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

I've found a lot of information on how to allow connections ***in*** to the VM, but nothing on how to connect from the VM ***out*** to hosts on the network.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found the answer. Turns out this trivially easy. Just set up a bridged network adapter. That will allow your VM to be on your local network and talk to the outside world.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network", use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true
end
```

That's then reflected in my `netstat`, showing a new adapter (eth1):

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.8    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

Taken from here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html

In my particular case, I also had to set up a VPN to then connect to the server I needed to, but that's also possible with the bridged network.